# Error plotting the errorbar in the a bar plot created with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the comparison between sex in the activity of an enzyme. I already have the mean value and SD to create a bar plot. The bars are plot correctly, but the error bars appear in the wrong place.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
ggplot(data=descriptives_plot, aes(x=sex.1, y=mean) ) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean, ymax=sd),
                position = position_dodge(20))
```

But the output shows the following:
[image]

As you see the error bars appear inside the bar rather than on the top of the bar. Also, I am trying to only use +SD values.

Someone can give me hand with the code or if you struggle with the same issue before?

Any help is appreciated.

Stay all safe.

Comment: HI Carmen, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide your data with `dput(descriptives_plot)`? You can edit your question and paste the output as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that relies on two changes:

1. Plot the error bars first so the bottom half is clipped by the bar
2. The `ymin` and `ymax` values are absolute, not relative, so you need to add or subtract them from the mean.

```
ggplot(data=descriptives_plot, aes(x=sex.1, y=mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = sex.1, ymin=(mean-sd), ymax=(mean + sd), width = 0.5)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
descriptives_plot <- structure(list(sex.1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Females", "Males"
    ), class = "factor"), mean = c(14, 24), sd = c(3, 10)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey Ian, thank you. It work when I used the errorbar before the geom_bar code.

Comment: Done! Thanks again. Stay safe